# Length doesn't work in by() aggregation?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have some survey data that I want to describe by political party and state.

I'm having some trouble with the by() aggregation command. It works with lots of functions, but just not length(). Eg:

```
by(x, list(party=nn$info$party,state=nn$info$st),mean)
```

works fine but not

```
by(x, list(party=nn$info$party,state=nn$info$st),length)
```

Which returns an array filled not with the count of the data I'm looking for, but just a series of 1's. This is what it looks like for Alabama:

```
party: D
state: AL
[1] 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
party: I
state: AL
[1] 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
party: R
state: AL
[1] 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Very mystifying. Any ideas?

Comment: If you could write what `str(x)` said...

Comment: x is a vector of length n. nn$info$party and nn$info$st are both vectors (eg info is the data frame).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get the number of records for different groups of your data, then the easiest way to do it is usually with `table`. It isn't clear from your post which data frame you want to use – is it `x` or `nn$info`?  with this in mind, your code should look something like

```
with(nn$info, table(party, state=st))
```

Here's an example anyone can replicate, using the `Cars93` dataset in the `MASS` package.

```
> with(Cars93, table(Type, AirBags))
         AirBags
Type      Driver & Passenger Driver only None
  Compact                  2           9    5
  Large                    4           7    0
  Midsize                  7          11    4
  Small                    0           5   16
  Sporty                   3           8    3
  Van                      0           3    6
```

Comment: x is a vector (of length n), nn$info is a dataframe (with n rows). But this did the trick without any reference to x. Perfect!

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I'm going to guess that `x` is a data frame.  In which case `length` returns the number of columns, not the number of elements.  You want `nrow` instead.  Note that if `foo` is a data frame, getting a single column by `foo$bar` will return a data frame with one column.

```
> by(1:10, rep(1:5, 2), length)
rep(1:5, 2): 1
[1] 2
------------------------------------------------------------ 
rep(1:5, 2): 2
[1] 2
------------------------------------------------------------ 
rep(1:5, 2): 3
[1] 2
------------------------------------------------------------ 
rep(1:5, 2): 4
[1] 2
------------------------------------------------------------ 
rep(1:5, 2): 5
[1] 2
> by(data.frame(1:10), rep(1:5, 2), length)
rep(1:5, 2): 1
[1] 1
------------------------------------------------------------ 
rep(1:5, 2): 2
[1] 1
------------------------------------------------------------ 
rep(1:5, 2): 3
[1] 1
------------------------------------------------------------ 
rep(1:5, 2): 4
[1] 1
------------------------------------------------------------ 
rep(1:5, 2): 5
[1] 1
> by(data.frame(1:10), rep(1:5, 2), nrow)
rep(1:5, 2): 1
[1] 2
------------------------------------------------------------ 
rep(1:5, 2): 2
[1] 2
------------------------------------------------------------ 
rep(1:5, 2): 3
[1] 2
------------------------------------------------------------ 
rep(1:5, 2): 4
[1] 2
------------------------------------------------------------ 
rep(1:5, 2): 5
[1] 2
```

Comment: x is actually a vector of length n, nn$info a dataframe with n rows. What I was trying to do is summarize x by various factors in nn$info, eg, what is the average x of Republicans in Texas?